# external wifi suddenly stop working in debian 11

Tags: debian, wifi

First of all hello everyone ,

about a few days ago my external wifi suddenly stop working, before that it works fine.
external wifi is :- Realtek RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
i have also downloaded proper driver firmware-realtek
and the command i use to get this was sudo tail -n 0 -f /var/log/syslog

```
Jun 17 17:30:05 debian kernel: [ 3071.519443] usb 4-2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian kernel: [ 3071.686056] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8176, bcdDevice= 2.00
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian kernel: [ 3071.686067] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian kernel: [ 3071.686073] usb 4-2: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian kernel: [ 3071.686078] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Realtek
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian kernel: [ 3071.686083] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian kernel: [ 3071.687052] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian kernel: [ 3071.795577] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian kernel: [ 3071.795800] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian kernel: [ 3071.795858] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian kernel: [ 3071.795919] ieee80211 phy3: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian kernel: [ 3071.798112] usb 4-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian NetworkManager[1028]: <info>  [1655467206.2654] device (wlan1): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian NetworkManager[1028]: <info>  [1655467206.2672] manager: (wlan1): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8)
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb4/4-2"
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian NetworkManager[1028]: <info>  [1655467206.8913] rfkill6: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/ieee80211/phy3/rfkill6) (driver rtl8192cu)
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian systemd-udevd[5801]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v247'.
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian upowerd[2643]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb4/4-2
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian systemd-udevd[5801]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian kernel: [ 3072.435580] rtl8192cu 4-2:1.0 wlx000f009afb44: renamed from wlan1
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian NetworkManager[1028]: <info>  [1655467206.9143] device (wlan1): interface index 6 renamed iface from 'wlan1' to 'wlx000f009afb44'
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian NetworkManager[1028]: <info>  [1655467206.9367] device (wlx000f009afb44): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian kernel: [ 3072.479043] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb4/4-2"
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian systemd-udevd[5808]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v247'.
Jun 17 17:30:06 debian kernel: [ 3072.519673] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
Jun 17 17:30:07 debian systemd-udevd[5808]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jun 17 17:30:07 debian NetworkManager[1028]: <info>  [1655467207.5734] device (wlx000f009afb44): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 9E:54:F0:13:9E:55 (scanning)
Jun 17 17:30:07 debian kernel: [ 3073.110921] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
Jun 17 17:30:07 debian kernel: [ 3073.144439] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
Jun 17 17:30:08 debian NetworkManager[1028]: <info>  [1655467208.2268] device (wlx000f009afb44): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Jun 17 17:30:08 debian NetworkManager[1028]: <info>  [1655467208.2270] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlx000f009afb44 created
Jun 17 17:30:08 debian NetworkManager[1028]: <info>  [1655467208.2275] manager: (p2p-dev-wlx000f009afb44): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/9)
Jun 17 17:30:08 debian NetworkManager[1028]: <info>  [1655467208.2289] device (p2p-dev-wlx000f009afb44): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 17 17:30:08 debian NetworkManager[1028]: <warn>  [1655467208.2323] sup-iface[4f1c29ddf8600cb4,4,wlx000f009afb44]: call-p2p-cancel: failed with P2P cancel failed
Jun 17 17:30:08 debian NetworkManager[1028]: <info>  [1655467208.2330] device (wlx000f009afb44): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 17 17:30:08 debian NetworkManager[1028]: <warn>  [1655467208.2356] device (wlx000f009afb44): wifi-scan: active scanning for networks due to profiles with wifi.hidden=yes. This makes you trackable
Jun 17 17:30:08 debian NetworkManager[1028]: <info>  [1655467208.2365] device (p2p-dev-wlx000f009afb44): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 17 17:30:09 debian ModemManager[1066]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb4/4-2': not supported by any plugin
```

but my internal laptop wifi card work.
I think it a hardware problem of my wifi card because i reinstalled debian but the problem is still standing.

Comment: Note the message: `rfkill6: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/ieee80211/phy3/rfkill6) (driver rtl8192cu)`. Does your laptop have a physical switch for disabling radio transmitters (for airplane mode, hospital ICUs etc.)? If so, check if that switch has been accidentally turned off. `sudo rfkill list` should tell you the current state of both software and hardware RF killswitches.

Comment: @telcoM well yes my laptop has a physical switch but it turned on and when i check current state of software and hardware in RF killswitches it says no block to all wifi and bluetooth.

Comment: most of time when i try to connect with a network it say  `Jun 21 17:48:01 debian NetworkManager[426]: <info>  [1655813881.3759] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="21bab4de-4c64-4c22-beec-24fe7ea99192" name="Redmi 9 Prime" pid=2044 uid=1000 result="fail" reason="Connection 'Redmi 9 Prime' is not available on device wlx000f009afb44 because profile is not compatible with device (mismatching interface name)"
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments:

> `Jun 21 17:48:01 debian NetworkManager[426]: <info>  [1655813881.3759] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="21bab4de-4c64-4c22-beec-24fe7ea99192" name="Redmi 9 Prime" pid=2044 uid=1000 result="fail" reason="Connection 'Redmi 9 Prime' is not available on device wlx000f009afb44 because profile is not compatible with device (mismatching interface name)"`

This message indicates NetworkManager is trying to activate a connection named `Redmi 9 Prime` (your mobile phone in hotspot mode, I guess?) but that connection has been configured to use a particular network interface whose name is not `wlx000f009afb44`.

This could be fixed by deleting the interface name from the configuration of the connection. From the command line, you could do it with:

```
nmcli c modify "Redmi 9 Prime" connection.interface-name ""
```

Deleting the interface name should make the connection available with any WiFi interface, both internal & external.

`man nm-settings-nmcli` has this to say about the `connection.interface-name` parameter:

> The name of the network interface this connection is bound to. If not set, then the connection can be attached to any interface of the appropriate type (subject to restrictions imposed by other settings). For software devices this specifies the name of the created device. For connection types where interface names cannot easily be made persistent (e.g. mobile broadband or USB Ethernet), this property should not be used. Setting this property restricts the interfaces a connection can be used with, and if interface names change or are reordered the connection may be applied to the wrong interface.

Comment: thank you for answer, i tried this and it start to connect with my mobile hotspot but wifi strength is none after few second it disconnected i got this from /var/log/syslog `(wlx000f009afb44): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
(p2p-dev-wlx000f009afb44): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
(wlx000f009afb44): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')`

Comment: Looks like NetworkManager is trying to use WiFi Direct (aka WiFi P2P), then disables it, but it somehow causes the main `wlx000f009afb44` to disable too. [Unfortunately it looks like NetworkManager doesn't yet offer an option to disable WiFi P2P.](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/537)

Comment: i read those thread and doc but i can't understand how to disable p2p. could you help me to disable it  and run my external wifi like before.

Comment: That thread seems to say NetworkManager has no way to disable p2p yet. Assuming that's true, you would have to remove that WiFi interface from NetworkManager control (`nmcli d set wlx000f009afb44 managed no`), then write a stand-alone `wpa_supplicant.conf` file for this wireless network, with the `p2p_disabled=1` WPA supplicant configuration setting included, and manually start `wpa_supplicant` for this interface/connection - and that would be a tricky workaround for something that seems to be a firmware or driver bug.

Comment: Instead, you might want to read `/var/log/dpkg.log` to see what updates your system might have received "a few days ago" when the problem appeared. In particular, if `wpasupplicant` or `firmware-realtek` packages have been upgraded, you might want to downgrade them to the previous version to see if it fixes the problem - and send in a bug report if you find that a downgrade fixes it.

Comment: Thank you much for your help. I am frustrated of this so the question is closed now